# Is it possible to rewrite this JSON to access an object by it's field? - Example Given

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON text.

```js
content = 

    [
      {
        "location": "page-home",
        "id": "block2",
        "title": "Design",
        "body": "<p>some content blah blah </p>",
        "image": false
      },
      {
        "location": "page-home",
        "id": "block1",
        "title": "Business",
        "body": "more here woooo</p>",
        "image": false
      },
      {
        "location": "page-home",
        "id": "welcome",
        "title": "Welcome",
        "body": "<p>blah blha blah on time and on budget.</p>\r\n",
        "image": false
      }
    ]
```

Right now, if I want to get the object with the ID title, I have to do this.

```
content.filter(function(item){
      return item.location == "page-home";         
  }
```

I was wondering if it's possible for me to parse the JSON I have so that I can simply do `content.page-home`, `content.page-home.title`

Comment: Well that dash is not doing to let you use dot notation and the way you want to access it, you should be using an object instead of an array of objects. You also have 3 things with "page-home" so not sure how that works.

Comment: when the location is always the same `page-home` then what's the point of filter?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to change the structure of your data, you need an `object of objects` that the key of each object is an **unique key**, in this case i will use the `id` of your object but if can be anything:

```
content =
{
  "block2":{
    "location": "page-home",
    "id": "block2",
    "title": "Design",
    "body": "<p>some content blah blah </p>",
    "image": false
  },
  "block1": {
    "location": "page-home",
    "id": "block1",
    "title": "Business",
    "body": "more here woooo</p>",
    "image": false
  },
  "welcome": {
    "location": "page-home",
    "id": "welcome",
    "title": "Welcome",
    "body": "<p>blah blha blah on time and on budget.</p>\r\n",
    "image": false
  }
}
```

In this example instead of accessing the way you want `content.page-home.title` you should do this:

`content.block1.title`

**EDIT:**
If you want to convert your data to an object of objects you can do this:

```
let obj = content.reduce( (acc, item) => {
    // Here you are creating a new object with the id of the current item, and assigning the whole object to this
    return acc[item.id] =  acc;
} ,{} )
```